# How to check if two time ranges are overlapping?

Tags: java

I have a requirement where I can create 3 shifts per day. The shift timings are:

```
 06:00 - 14:00   
 14:01 - 22:00   
 22:01 - 05:59.
```

How can I check that shift timings are not overlapped? Please note that in the 3rd case **from hour** is greater than **to hour**.

Comment: How about having if else ?

Comment: Just a friendly tip, you may want to read over this page: [The How-To-Ask Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you can always be sure that your questions are easily answerable and as clear as possible. Be sure to include any efforts you've made to fix the problem you're having, and what happened when you attempted those fixes. Also don't forget to your show code and any error messages!

Comment: @Matthew Cliatt Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜ ᴀᴛᴛᴀ. Thanks for your suggestion. Let me try my best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have solved the problem my self. please find below.

```
public void checkIfTimesOverlapped(){


// eft - existed FROM TIME
// ett - existed TO TIME
// cft - current entered FROM TIME
// ctt - current entered TO TIME
// Note : same FROM TIME and TO TIME is not allowed. so not checking. 

float eft = 22.00f; 
float ett = 05.00f;
float cft = 23.00f;
float ctt = 24.00f;


    if (cft < ctt) {
        if (eft < ett) {
            if(cft<=ett && ctt>=eft){
                System.out.println("overlapped");
            }

        } else if(eft > ett) {
            if(!(cft>ett && ctt<eft)){
                System.out.println("overlapped");
            }
        }
    } else if (cft > ctt) {

        if (eft < ett) {
            if((cft>=eft && cft<=ett) || (ctt>=eft && ctt<=ett)){
                System.out.println("overlapped");
            }

        } else if(eft > ett) {
            // already one shift existed with FROM TIME > TO TIME. so again FROM TIME > TO TIME is not possible
            System.out.println("overlapped");
        }

    }
```

}

Comment: You should follow a [style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html). It will make your code more readable, and easier to debug. It's very important to name your variables more descriptively. You shouldn't have to include a comment to show what your variables are used for. Instead of naming your variables like `eft` and `ett`, name them: `existingFrom` and `existingTo` or maybe `originalFrom` or `originalTo`.